# Required rule for all properties in entity framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I'm using code first with fluent API in Entity Framework Core to determinate behaviors for properties.

I wondering if there is any way to replace this part.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(b => b.Name)
            .IsRequired();

 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(b => b.LastName)
            .IsRequired();

 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .Property(b => b.Age)
            .IsRequired();
```

With a something like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .AllProperties()
            .IsRequired();
```

The point is that sometimes most properties or even all need to be NOT NULL. And it's not elegant to mark each property.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution may be using reflection:

```cs
var properties = typeof(Class).GetProperties();

foreach (var prop in properties)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Class>()
        .Property(prop.PropertyType, prop.Name)
        .IsRequired();
}
```

Note that ALL of the properties will be setted as required. Of course you may filter the properties to be setted as required based on type (for example).

**UPDATE**

Using an extension method you can make it much cleaner.

*EntityTypeBuilderExtensions.cs*

```cs
public static class EntityTypeBuilderExtensions
{
    public static List<PropertyBuilder> AllProperties<T>(this EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder, 
        Func<PropertyInfo, bool> filter = null) where T : class
    {
        var properties = typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .AsEnumerable();

        if (filter != null)
        {
            properties = properties
                .Where(filter);
        }

        return properties
            .Select(x => builder.Property(x.PropertyType, x.Name))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage in your `DbContext`:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Class>()
        .AllProperties()
        .ForEach(x => x.IsRequired());
}
```

If you want to apply `IsRequired` only to particular properties of a class you can pass a filter function to the `AllProperties` method.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Required is applied only for string properties
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<Class>()
        .AllProperties(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        .ForEach(x => x.IsRequired());
}
```

Comment: Seems nice, what if I would to apply it only on `LastName` property?

Comment: For only one property you can use the standard way: `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(b => b.LastName).IsRequired();`. If you really want to use the extension method you can do it with: `modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().AllProperties(x => x.Name == nameof(Person.LastName)).ForEach(x => x.IsRequired());`